# How do I invoke a CSS3 transition using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

When I click on a button, I want a div to rotate, just as I would do with a CSS3 `transition: rotate(350deg);`. How would I do this with either CSS or JS? (If it can be done with CSS I'd perfer that instead)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activating Webkit CSS3 animation using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033509/activating-webkit-css3-animation-using-javascript)

Comment: you can't animate with css2 as there's no transition; you will have to use jQuery and a plugin for it, google around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onclick` event of the button, put:

`document.getElementById("yourDivId").className += " rotate";`

In the CSS:

```
#yourDivId {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

You'd have to add the browser specfic prefixes (-moz-, -webkit-) to the transition and transform, but this should work for you.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could add [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) to avoid having to declare different vendor-specific attributes.